# С дефисом или слитно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Открытие фонда американцев бухарскоеврейского происхождения.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: *Открытие фонда американцев **бухарско-еврейского** происхождения.*

**Пояснение**

В сложном прилагательном дефис обозначает **сочинительную**, а не подчинительную связь.

13 марта в Баку, в рамках XXIV съезда Всемирного конгресса бухарских евреев, состоялась церемония «Человек года-2024». Мероприятие подвело итоги деятельности **бухарско-еврейских** общин по всему миру за последний год.

Существует термин: **бухарско-еврейский** язык.

**Бухарско-еврейский язык** — Еврейско-таджикский диалект (бухори, еврейско-бухарский) — разговорный и литературный язык бухарских евреев, один из еврейско-иранских языков. Фактически является говором таджикского языка.

**[Бухарские евреи. Кто они и откуда появились в Узбекистане](https://dzen.ru/a/YHP-j2WUM32Bg4MC)**